# Dictionary that holds a specific generic type for a generic key in Swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have two classes like this:

```
class A: Hashable {}
class B<T: A> {}
```

I now want to have a Dictionary that holds a class B for key A.
Something like this:

```
var dict: [A : B<A>]
```

I don't know if an how something like this is possible in Swift. Does anyone know how to do this? Or another way to have some kind of List of different B?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dict: [A : B<A>.Type]
```

And save value as `dict[a] = T.self`, where `T: B`.